# How do I remove some text from "get_text()" output in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm making a web scraping program to get the retail trading sentiment from IG Markets.

The output I would like to be displayed in the console is:

```
     "EUR/USD: 57% of clients accounts are short on this market".
```

The output I get right now is:

```
     "EUR/USD:  57% of client accounts are short on this market The percentage of IG client    
      accounts with positions in this market that are currently long or short. Calculated  
      to the nearest 1%."
```

How do I remove this text:

```
        "The percentage of IG client accounts with positions in this market that are  
         currently long or short. Calculated to the nearest 1%."
```

Thank you.

Here's the code:

```
import bs4, requests

def getIGsentiment(pairUrl):
    res = requests.get(pairUrl)
    res.raise_for_status()

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
    elems = soup.select('.price-ticket__sentiment')
    return elems[0].get_text(" ", strip = True)

retail_positions = getIGsentiment('https://www.ig.com/us/forex/markets-forex/eur-usd')
print('EUR/USD:  ' + retail_positions)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your string changes but the capitalization not, you can simply create a for loop to look after the 7th upper character and split the string. In this case, it's the letter 'T'.

Something like this:

```
phrase = "EUR/USD:  57 % of client accounts are short on this market The percentage of 
IG client accounts with positions in this market that are currently long or short. 
Calculated to the nearest 1 % ."

upperchars = []
for char in phrase:
    if char.isupper():
        upperchars.append(char)

final = phrase.split(upperchars[6])[0]
print(final)
```

The result would be:

EUR/USD:  57 % of client accounts are short on this market

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Regular expression (regex)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for that :

```py
>>> import re
>>> print('EUR/USD:  ' + re.match('^.*on this market',retail_positions).group())
EUR/USD:  57% of client accounts are short on this market
```

You express a search pattern (`^.*on this market`) and `re.match()` will return a `re.Match` object and you can retrieve the match with the `group()` function.

This search pattern consist of 3 parts :

- `^` match the start of the line
- `.*` mean to match *zero or more* (`*`) instance of *any character* (`.`)
- `on this market` literally match this string

Regex are widely used and supported, but beware some variants, Python don't seem to support the `[[:digit:]]` character class...

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to scrape their website to get this info, IG have [APIs](https://labs.ig.com/). Using the [trading_ig](https://pypi.org/project/trading-ig/) library:

```
ig_service = IGService(username, password, api_key)
ig_service.create_session()
print(ig_service.fetch_client_sentiment_by_instrument("US500"))
```

gives

```
INFO:trading_ig.rest:POST '/session', resp 200
Munch({'marketId': 'US500', 'longPositionPercentage': 59.0, 'shortPositionPercentage': 41.0})
INFO:trading_ig.rest:GET '/clientsentiment/US500', resp 200
```